# Как создать историю решений для web - Калькулятора, без применения БД? Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Я разрабатываю веб - калькулятор на Django, в котором будет присутствовать история решений. Каждое решение в истории - это объект с полями "Выражение", "Ответ", "Дата выполнения решения". Подскажите, как мне реализовать историю решений, не применяя БД? Где мне хранить эти все объекты, а самое главное, как сделать так, чтобы в новой сессии у пользователя была новая история, которая будет также заполняться по мере подсчетов пользователя?